# Crossbar.io - Preventing spam/flooding in a chat application

Tags: crossbar

In a Crossbar.io application, what's to stop a publisher from doing something like:

```
setInterval(function() { session.publish(topicUri, [randomStr]); }, 10);
```

My understanding is there is no way to identify a publisher that doesn't disclose itself. Identification could at least help in blocking abusive publishers. If a publication can't be stopped, is there a way to help subscribers block flooding attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Crossbar also support RPC call. 
For chat will be better create RPC backend function like add_message() that will publishing messages from users. And set permissions for user(or anonymous)/backend like:

```
{
   "name": "user",
   "permissions": [
       {
           "uri": "*",
           "subscribe": true,
           "call": true

       }
   ]
},
{
   "name": "backend",
   "permissions": [
       {
           "uri": "*",
           "publish": true,
           "subscribe": true,
           "call": true,
           "register": true
       }
   ]
}
```

Now user can only subscribe and call RPC functions (publishing via backend) and you can analyze messages on backend for prevent any flood